# How Can I Trigger a CSS Animation After a Framer Motion Animation Completes?

Tags: framer-motion

I have a component that's inside a Framer Motion div.  That component has a CSS animation, but the timing for the animation is off, because the Framer Motion animation takes a variable amount of time to complete.

What I'd like is someway to tell Framer Motion "do your animation, but then tell me when you are done, so I can trigger my other animation".  Is that possible?

The code for the Framer Motion element is:

```
 <motion.section
      initial={{ x: 100, opacity: 0 }}
      animate={{ x: 0, opacity: 1 }}
      transition={{ when: 'beforeChildren'}}
    >
      <MyComponent/>
    </motion.section>
```

`MyComponent` has its own CSS animation, triggered with a `useEffect` and some DOM manipulation to add a class:

```
 const MyComponent = () => {
      useEffect(() =>{
        const id = getFromUrl();
        document.getElementById(id).classList.add('animation-class');
      }, [])
      // ... rest of component ...
 }
```

Here's the CSS for the animation:

```
 .purple-highlight {
   animation: glow 5s infinite alternate;
   animation-iteration-count: 1;
   animation-timing-function: linear;
 }

 @keyframes glow {
   0% {
     box-shadow: 8px 0 5px 1px var(--purple-500);
   }
   100% {
     box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 var(--purple-500);
   }
 }
```

The problem is, the `5s` in the animation CSS is either too short or too long.  If the Framer Motion stuff takes awhile, the CSS animation finishes before it even becomes visible ... but if I set it to `20s` then when Framer finishes more quickly, the animation lasts too long.

Hopefully there's some way to trigger code after Framer Motion is done with its animation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Framer Motion adds some [animation events](https://www.framer.com/motion/component/##animation-events) to each `motion` element. You can add the `onAnimationComplete` prop to your motion element that will run when each animation is complete.

```
<motion.section
  initial={{ x: 100, opacity: 0 }}
  animate={{ x: 0, opacity: 1 }}
  transition={{ when: 'beforeChildren'}}
  onAnimationComplete={() => alert('Animation Complete!')}
>
  <MyComponent/>
</motion.section>
```

Here is a [working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/onanimationcomplete-example-framer-motion?file=app%2Fpage.tsx).